# The provided grant has not been issued for this endpoint. Actual Value : B2C_1_SignUp_SignIn and Expected Value : B2C_1_SignUp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm currently using the Azure AD B2C Sign up User Flow with a custom Sign up Challenge that allows my users to be directed straight to the sign up page without having to go to the sign in (Sign up and Sign in) page first.

[image]

```
public IActionResult SignUp([FromRoute] string scheme)
    {
        scheme ??= OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        var redirectUrl = Url.Content("/user/sign-up");
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl };
        properties.Items["policy"] = _azureAdB2C.SignUpPolicyId;
        return Challenge(properties, scheme);
    }
```

Once a user signs up they are redirected to their user profile, the user profile information is retrieved from another api I have built, I generate the access token for the api by using [ITokenAcquisition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.itokenacquisition?view=msal-model-dotnet-latest).

```
var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { "MyScope" }, null);
```

However this is where I'm running into an issue. I'm receiving the following error when trying to retrieve the access token:

> Message: IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent.
>
> InnerException: AADB2C90088: The provided grant has not been issued for this endpoint.
> Actual Value : B2C_1_SignUp_SignIn and Expected Value :
> B2C_1_SignUp Correlation ID:
> 134e1d8a-85e0-4154-a8e3-c58339d69486 Timestamp: 2023-06-07 00:03:49Z

Obviously if I use the `B2C_1_SignUp_SignIn` policy, `GetAccessTokenForUserAsync` it works fine but I'm wondering if there is anyway to provide the correct grant for the `B2C_1_SignUp` policy? as I'd prefer my users to be directed to the sign up first rather than having to go to the sign in page.